# Retrieve information with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I use request to log in to this page:  Now I would like to retrieve this information Legal Name Registered At Registration Authority Entity ID Legal Jurisdiction Entity Legal Form Code Entity Status And add them in my dataframe with BeautifulSoup, but I don't know how to do it. And when I print the text with Request, it's too long to do text matching

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.lei-lookup.com/#!record;lei=335800NV2ZZ3157KUJ54', verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Hey @Tiffany Zucman welcome to SO! what so far you have tried to implement please add that too and what errors did you get so it will be better for understanding!

Comment: I have this, but I don't know how to get the parts I need with beautifulsoup <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" rel="profile"/>
  <script>
   /**
   * Function that registers a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
   * This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string

Comment: the page you requested in dynamic so you need selenium to get the data

Comment: I can't install selenium on my machine, because you need the ex's path, and I can't install ex on my machine

Comment: agree with @Abhishek you can't get data with only requests, you need selenium for that

Comment: @TiffanyZucman you can try with seleniumwire it needs no path

Answer (score 1):

from xhr you can get the data for that go to network tab and call url that contains above data which is present as json and in which `body` contains tags so from `bs4` we can extract text as output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.lei-lookup.com/record/api/335800NV2ZZ3157KUJ54')

main_data=r.json()
html=main_data['body']
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
rows=soup.find("div",class_="details-table-row").find_all("div",class_="row")
for row in rows:
   
    print(row.select_one("div.title-block").text,end=" ")
    print(row.select_one("div.value-block").text)
```

Output:

```
Legal Name CASUAL CLOTHING COMPANY
Registered At RA000709
Registration Authority Entity ID 3294013167
Legal Jurisdiction IN
Entity Legal Form Code A0PS
Entity Status ACTIVE
```

Comment: clever approach with json

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just one last thing, how do you put each entity in a pandas like column (Legal Name, Registered At, Registration Authority Entity ID, Legal Jurisdiction, Entity Legal Form Code, Entity Status) And the values ​​in line (CASUAL CLOTHING COMPANY, RA000709, 3294013167, IN, A0PS, ACTIVE)

Comment: you can pass it like column wise or appending into list use that list in direct dataframe may be

Comment: Thanks. Can you put an example in your code please?

Comment: I think try  you should try from your side and if you get any errors create separate post for it so it will be good if possible you can accept this answer!

Comment: But if you can give me an example that would be cool. As it is we code it would be easy for me then to understand

Comment: @Tiffany Zucman  you can raise second question for adding values to dataframe